# Laravel group inside group not working, its not seeing the namespace param

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

Maybe it's me for doing something stupid or I don't understand the grouping of routes in Laravel 8.

It's showing the error

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SettingsController] does not exist.

Even when I empty the cache

```
\Controllers
- Admin
-- Settings
--- Settingscontroller
--- SomeController
--- ...
```

**routes/admin.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

// the normal way
// use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Settings\SettingsController;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    // not working
    Route::group(['namespace'=>'Settings'],function() {
        Route::get('settings', [SettingsController::class, 'index']);
        Route::post('settings/update', [SettingsController::class, 'update']);
    });
    
    //working
    Route::get('settings', [Settings\SettingsController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('settings/update', [Settings\SettingsController::class, 'update']);
    
});
```

Comment: `SettingsController::class` already returns the fully qualified name. No `namespace` grouping needed.

Comment: sorry I forgot to added a folder in my example

Comment: What is the `use` statement that corresponds with `SettingsController::class`?

Comment: Updated my example with the use...

Comment: PHP expects `SettingController::class` to be in the current namespace (which is `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`) if it's not imported via `use`.

Comment: Isnt the namespace extending the path to App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Settings ? As the Admin is the main parent, as I have multiple subfolder

Comment: I don't think so. I guess, it doesn't work with `::class` since the return value is already fully qualified. The group's `'namespace'` would be applied after the files `namespace` is resolved and that'd be too late.

Answer (score 1):

`SettingsController::class` already returns the [fully qualified name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php). No `'namespace'` grouping needed. PHP expects `SettingController::class` to be in the current namespace (which is `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` according to the `namespace` statement in the file's first line) if it's not imported via `use`. I guess, it doesn't work with `::class` since the return value is already fully qualified. The group's 'namespace' would be applied after the files namespace is resolved and that'd be too late.

1. Class name is `SettingsController`
2. PHP looks for the class in the specified `namespace` or global if file has none
3. Namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` is prepended to the class name so now it is fully qualified as `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SettingsController`
4. Laravel's route gets group attributes applied. At that point, it doesn't make sense to either prepend or append `'Settings'` because you'd need it in the middle of the class name.